# How can I tap a pin on Google Maps using Appium in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ruby, google-maps, appium

> Problem:

I'm having an issue using Appium to test Google Maps implemented in a native, internal iOS app.  Specifically, I cannot get Appium to interact with the pins generated by the app that appear in the map.  The pins cannot be found or identified in any way through Appium inspector.

The expectation is that when I click a pin an information box will appear above it with pertinent data.

> Questions:

How can I get Appium to start interacting with those Google Map pins in my native iOS app?  Is Appium capable of this?  If not, what should I be using for this testing?

> Solutions I have tried (unsuccessfully):

- **Clicking at the coordinates of the pin**.  Since I set the location on the map every time it opens, and since I know what pins will be there and where, I figured that I could just have Appium tap at an X/Y coordinate.  Unfortunately, this does not work - nothing happens.  Here's what I used to try to tap at the specific X/Y coordinate:

  `Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 100, y: 200, fingers:1).release.perform`
- **Switching to WEBVIEW_3**.  I tried switching the context of the driver to Webview_3, thinking that might work.  Unfortunately, when I do this, the driver doesn't recognize ANY elements in the app, rendering it useless.  Here's the code I used to try this:

  `set_context “WEBVIEW_3"
  get_page_class`

  'get_page_class' returns nil, meaning there are no elements found in this context.  When I run it in "NATIVE_APP", many elements are found.

> Information on what I'm using:

- Appium 1.4.13
- Ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
- appium_lib (8.0.1, 8.0.0, 7.0.0, 6.0.0)
- Simulator: iPad Air 2, iOS 9.0, Portrait orientation (have tried other device and iOS implementations - none work)
- Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code to provide where we can see what the issue is?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, David.  I updated the "Solutions I have tried" section with some examples of code I have tried to tap at coordinates and switch contexts.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out!  After looking through other ideas of executing javascript, looking at porting the tests over to Xcode, etc., I started examining "Appium::TouchAction" again, mostly through the site http://www.rubydoc.info/github/appium/ruby_lib/Appium/TouchAction

I was using this (as noted above):

```
Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 100, y: 200, fingers:1).release.perform
```

Looking at the different methods on that webpage for TouchAction, I noticed there is also a "press" action.  So, I tried that:

```
Appium::TouchAction.new.press(x: 100, y: 200).wait(5).release.perform
```

This worked like a charm!  I wondered - was it the "press" that worked or the "wait(5)"?  I tried the "press" code again without the "wait" and it failed.  I then tried it with the "wait" and with a "tap":

```
Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 100, y: 200).wait(5).release.perform
```

This worked, too.

### Conclusion:

I fixed the issue by adding ".wait(5)" after the tap